# Polygon boundary is not properly connected in R

Tags: r, polygon, ggplot2

I have two points sets, when plotted using geom_point, they look like:
[image]

What I want to do is draw a polygon using these two datasets, and I expect to get a ring-shape polygon. However, when I use geom_path to draw the boundary, I got a weird result that boundaries are not properly closed.
[image]
I think the problem may due to the order of the dataframes, but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you combining the two? What does each one *on its own* look like as a path? Can you focus on the ends and check the order? Do you know which way round to trace each line to make the figure you expect? Without your data we can't really help more.

Comment: Is there anyway to upload data? I think it would be better if you can directly see them

Comment: Use a sharing site like dropbox, box, etc and make public. Save R objects as RDS using `saveRDS` if you don't have text files.